# How to update CoreData entries when an array is used to originally save the data, but isn’t actually an attribute in the Entity

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

My question boils down to:  how to update CoreData entries when an array is used to originally save the data, but isn’t actually an attribute in the Entity.

I’ll explain:

Today, I can edit a CoreData object using @ObservedObject like this:

[image]

This makes sense to me because each item I’m looking to update exists as an attribute to the CoreData Entity.

However, I’ve updated my Project entity to have an inverse relationship with a new Entity: CapturedImage using the relationship capturedimages

[image]

[image]

In this new setup, instead of saving 4 individual images to Project image1, image2, image3, and image4, I’m now saving images to CapturedImage, where
`@State var images: [Data] = []`

[image]

This works great for allowing me to not have to pre-determine how many images the user might want to save. Then I can display the images using a ForEach.

**Here’s the question**

I’m stuck trying to figure out how to create an **Edit** view using this new setup. Since `images` is not an attribute stored in my **Project** Entity, and is only used to temporarily hold the array of images when creating the object, I don’t know how to satisfy the initializer. So far every attempt to initialize it has failed.

[image]

Thanks so much!

[EDIT 1]
After breaking it down some more, I think the issues lies with how I’m initializing

`self._capturedimages = State(wrappedValue: ([project.capturedimages] as? [Data] ?? [capturedimages]))`

And that instead of referring to `images` in the view, I should be referring to `capturedimages`

The error I get is "**Cannot convert value of type '[Data]?' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Data’)**” … So I think it’s that last part, the `[capturedimages]` that I can’t quite get right.

Comment: It looks like you need `@State var capturedImages: [Data]?` - i.e. you may have no captured images.  Right now you are trying to use a nil coalescing operator to assign `capturedImages` to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the key lies with how I'm initializing `self._capturedimages = State(wrappedValue: ([project.capturedimages] as? [Data] ?? [capturedimages]))` -- I get the error Cannot convert value of type '[Data]?' to expected element type 'Array<Data>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Data')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SwiftUI you shouldn't init objects in `View` struct inits. The reason is that these View structs are just lightweight values that are created and thrown every time there is a state change in the parent and the parent's body re-inits the `View` struct. Initing an object inside a View struct is basically a memory leak. That is why we have `@StateObject` property wrapper that will only init the object once - right before body is called (not just if init was called) but that is for a different purpose entirely.

You need to re-architect so that the `Project` managed object is init in an action, e.g. a button handler or an an `@State` optional struct init or in a mutating func in a `@State` struct that you call from a button handler.

For ideas, you could take a look at this [CoreDataBooks-SwiftUI](https://github.com/malhal/CoreDataBooks-SwiftUI) example I created.